# Set react-datepicker time input start time but not selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set a DatePicker that has date + time, but when the initial date picker loads, the time input shows 6 PM (even when inspecting the element, shows value = 18:00). When I select the default of 6 PM, the selected value prints 12 AM. Is there a way to just inject/set the start time in the datepicker input to be 12 AM? I want to make this code as simple as possible.

I'm using the standard date-picker props and a function to handleChange, but it looks like when I try to set the `selected` prop to be `setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 0)` it breaks when I change to a different day/time.

Here's the generic code from the reactdatepicker webpage that I'm trying to modify. Mine looks slightly different but just wanting to set the time input:

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      timeIntervals={15}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
    />
  );
};
```

I've also tried hard-coding `document.getElementsByName("time-input")[0].setAttribute("value", "00:00")` but that doesn't work. Any ideas anyone may have is helpful as I haven't worked with React a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of updating the date object you receive from the datepicker component and change it the way you want it. Then, update your hook state.

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  handleDateChange = (date) => {
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setStartDate(date);
  };
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      timeIntervals={15}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
    />
  );
};
```

Hope that helps.